# Looking for OCR API on mobile platform

Tags: android, ios, library, ocr

I'm looking for an OCR library that runs on Android, iOS & Windows Phone.

My app scans the image to find certain information on it. For example, scan a parking ticket to get time information on it.

[Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is free and open source, but need port to Android, iOS & Windows Phone. Also need to tweak to improve the accuracy.

[Camscanner API](https://dev.camscanner.net/developers) is not free, but looks much better: - Support Android and iOS apps. - Test CamScanner App, it's very accurate.

Is there any other tool available(both free and commercial)?

Comment: What kind of content are you trying to OCR? For instance, OCR for Vietnamese, or for digits only, might be best with a particular library.

Comment: It is now 2016, do you still need Windows Phone? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Pay attention for products by ABBYY:

- [ABBYY Mobile OCR Engine](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm) is highly-accurate OCR SDK. It supports Android and iOS, works on device.
- [ABBYY Cloud OCR SDK](https://www.abbyy.com/en-us/cloud-ocr-sdk/) is platform-independent OCR SDK, works in cloud.

Comment: The ABBYY OCR SDK does not yet support Windows Phone.

Comment: Could you please add pricing information? You talk about accuracy, but a link to a study proving the accuracy would be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to use a commercial product you should check out LEADTOOLS Mobile SDK. You will be able to develop in either [Android](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/android), [iOS](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ios-macos) or [Window's Phone](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/windows-phone).

Here is some sample code of how you would recognize text using Android OCR:

```
OcrEngine mOcrEngine = OcrEngineManager.createEngine(OcrEngineType.ADVANTAGE);
mOcrEngine.startup(null, null, null, OCR_RUNTIME_DIRECTORY);

ILeadStream leadStream = LeadStreamFactory.create(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ocr1_tif), true);
RasterImage rasterImage = mOcrEngine.getRasterCodecsInstance().load(leadStream, 1);

ocrPage = mOcrEngine.createPage(image, OcrImageSharingMode.AUTO_DISPOSE);
ocrPage.recognize(this);
String results = ocrPage.getText(-1);
```

Below is a screenshot of the LEADTOOLS OCR Demo running on Android

Scanned Image:

[image]

OCR Results:

[image]

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product